# Dimension of output in Dense layer Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have the sample following model

```
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras import layers

sample_model = models.Sequential()
sample_model.add(layers.Dense(32, input_shape=(4,)))
sample_model.add(layers.Dense(16, input_shape = (44,)))

sample_model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
                     optimizer="adam", metrics = ["accuracy"])
```

IP for the model:

```
sam_x = np.random.rand(10,4)
sam_y = np.array([0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,])
sample_model.fit(sam_x,sam_y)
```

The confusion is the `fit` should have thrown an error of `shape mismatch` as the `expected_input_shape` for the `2nd Dense Layer` is given as `(None,44)` but the `output` for the `1st Dense Layer` (which is the input of the `2nd Dense Layer`) will be of shape `(None,32)`. But it ran successfully.

I don't understand why there was no error. Any clarifications will be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `input_shape` keyword argument has an effect only on the first layer of a `Sequential`. The shape of the input of the other layers will be derived from their previous layer.

That behaviour is hinted in the doc of `tf.keras.layers.InputShape`:

> When using InputLayer with Keras Sequential model, it can be skipped by moving the input_shape parameter to the first layer after the InputLayer.

And in [the Sequential Model guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/sequential_model).

The behaviour can be confirmed by looking at the source of the [`Sequential.add` method](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py#L159-L236):

```
if not self._layers:
  if isinstance(layer, input_layer.InputLayer):
    # Case where the user passes an Input or InputLayer layer via `add`.
    set_inputs = True
  else:
    batch_shape, dtype = training_utils.get_input_shape_and_dtype(layer)
    if batch_shape:
      # Instantiate an input layer.
      x = input_layer.Input(
          batch_shape=batch_shape, dtype=dtype, name=layer.name + '_input')
      # This will build the current layer
      # and create the node connecting the current layer
      # to the input layer we just created.
      layer(x)
      set_inputs = True
```

If there is no layers yet in the model, then an `Input` will be added to the model with the shape derived from the first layer of the model. This is done **only** if no layer is present yet in the model.

That shape is either fully known (if `input_shape` has been passed to the first layer of the model) or will be fully known once the model is built (for example, with a call to `model.build(input_shape)`).

Answer (score 2):

The thing is after checking the `input shape` of the model from the **first layer**, it won't check or deal with other declared `input shape` inside that same model. For example, if you write your model the following way

```
sample_model.add(layers.Dense(32, input_shape=(4,)))
sample_model.add(layers.Dense(16, input_shape = (44,)))
sample_model.add(layers.Dense(8, input_shape = (32,)))
```

The program will always check the first declared `input shape` layer and discard the rest. So, if you start your first layer with `input_shape = (44,)`, you need to pass exact feature numbers to your model as input such as:

```
sam_x = np.random.rand(10,44)
sam_y = np.array([0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,])
sample_model.fit(sam_x,sam_y)
```

Additionally, if you look at the **Functional API**, unlike the **Sequential** model, you must create and define a standalone `Input` layer that specifies the shape of input data. It's not learnable but simply a spec layer. It's a kind of gateway of the input data for the model. That means even if we define `input_shape` inside the other layers, they all will be discarded. For example:

```
nputs = keras.Input(shape=(4,))

dense = layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(8,)) # dicard input_shape 
x = dense(inputs)

x = layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(16,))(x) # dicard input_shape 
outputs = layers.Dense(10)(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="mnist_model")
```

---

Here is a more complex example with `Conv2D` and MNIST.

```
encoder_input = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1),)
x = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu",  input_shape=[32,32,3])(encoder_input)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu",  input_shape=[64,64,3])(x) 
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(3)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu",  input_shape=[224,321,3])(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu",  input_shape=[420,32,3])(x)
x = layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)
out = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)

encoder = keras.Model(encoder_input, out, name="encoder")
encoder.summary()
```

```
Model: "encoder"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_15 (InputLayer)        [(None, 28, 28, 1)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 26, 26, 16)        160       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 24, 24, 32)        4640      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 8, 8, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)           (None, 6, 6, 32)          9248      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)           (None, 4, 4, 16)          4624      
_________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling2d_2 (Glob (None, 16)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_56 (Dense)             (None, 10)                170       
=================================================================
Total params: 18,842
Trainable params: 18,842
Non-trainable params: 0
```

```
def pre_process(image, label):
    return (image / 256)[...,None].astype('float32'), 
            tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(label, num_classes=10)

(x, y), (_, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data('mnist')
```

```
encoder.compile(
          loss      = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
          metrics   = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(),
          optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())

encoder.fit(x, y, batch_size=256)
4s 14ms/step - loss: 1.4303 - categorical_accuracy: 0.5279
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Keras will create (or preserves to create) an additional Input Layer - but as the second dense layer is added using `model.add()` it will automatically be connected to the layer before, and thus the extra input layer stays unconnected and **is not part of the model**.
(I agree that it would be nice of Keras to hint at unconnected layers, I sometimes created unconnected layers when using the functional API and changed the inputs. Keras doesn't remind me that I had jumped several layers, I just wondered why the `summary()` was so short...)